# How do i put this dynamic Jquery Variable in to this condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
      $(".mylink").live('click', function(){
    var linkid = $(this).attr('id');
    if($("#TBL").find('tbody > '+ #linkid ).css("display")=="inline"){
        // Do Somerthing 
     }
     });
```

I have to put the Dynamic variable "linkid"  in to the above  if condition  iam looking to have the interpreted value
.Iam getting "invalid character error.how do i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
$(".mylink").live('click', function() {
  if ($(this).css("display")=="inline") {
    // Do Somerthing 
  }
});
```

Since IDs *should* be unique, you can just use `this`, you should already have the only element with that ID.  If you have multiple elements with the same ID that's another issue that needs addressing, perhaps you should be using `href="#id"` for example, and `$(this.hash)` in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as:

```
.find("tbody > #" + linkid);
```

You can put the `#` sign directly into Javascript. Because `#linkid` is not valid Javascript.

To be extra careful, you might want to use a regular expression to escape CSS3 characters that are in the ID. See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F) for more information on what characters need to be escaped.

**UPDATE**

Nick's answer is correct and works for your situation. I didn't notice that you were trying to use the id of the same element that you clicked on. `this` refers to the element that generated the click and so you shouldn't have to grab it again via jQuery.

In general, what I wrote above will work if you want to use a variable that contains an id, in a jQuery selector string.